# Unneccessary scrollbars appears in SharePoint intranet site but only for one user even when both using IE11

Tags: browser-compatibility

I've been working in IE11 on my company's SharePoint intranet site to fix an issue that caused no scrollbars to appear (which is very annoying as I'm sure you can imagine).
I edited the site CSS and master page and I thought the problem was resolved. However, now unnecessary scrollbars appear in the site pages but only for one user. This user is using the same IE11 browser that I am with all of the same settings (as far as I can tell), yet I do not see any unnecessary scroll bars but the bars (horizontal and vertical) appear for him on all site pages. As far as I know, other users in the company do not see the unnecessary scrollbars and everyone in the company uses the same version of IE.

Is this an issue that is caused by IE11 settings or even differences in computers? I've tested on my computer under many different circumstances and conditions but I can't get my browser to recreate the results that the other user is having. Both computers are running IE11 in Compatibility Mode and I went through all IE advanced settings to see if I could get the unnecessary scrollbars to appear for me.

The only other thing I can think of is that I have Full Control permissions for the site in question, and this user does not (only Read permissions). The other users that I know don't have unnecessary scrollbars also have Full Control permissions. Is it possible for permission level differences to have an effect on scrollbar appearance?

I'm a bit stumped. Any ideas as to what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you modified the master page and CSS, it's possible the changes haven't been published as major versions, checked in, and approved. This explains why it might not appear for people with Full Control vs someone with Read permission.

Comment: I think that may have been it. I checked my master page and it hadn't been published as a major version, so I published it and approved it. I'll find out tomorrow if it fixed the issue for the other user.
Thanks!

Comment: Okay, apparently that wasn't the issue. I have made sure all the files I edited are published as major versions, checked in, and approved.

I also checked with a few other users who had read permissions and they all have the unnecessary scroll bar as well. Are there any other reasons that the scroll bar might appear based on permissions?

Comment: Not that I can think of. Have the users tried clearing their browser cache? Perhaps they have an old cached copy of the CSS being used.

Comment: Actually, I've done some more digging and I think rather than being based on permissions, it is based on whether or not the ribbon at the top of the page is open (and the read only users can't see the ribbon, explaining why the scroll bar always appears for them). If the ribbon is open the scrollbar is not there, but when I close the ribbon the scroll bar comes back.